Error with Anchor build command (Solana)?
I building my app with anchor framework, but when I run command anchor build get issue
error: could not execute process `/home/<username>/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/rustc -vV` (never executed)

I didn't found any solves of this problem
